# Download Images to Local Folder from Urls in CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, urllib, enumeration

I made the program to get the Images from the Urls in the CSV file and want to download it in the Local Folder in Python but the program showing the below error

"TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"

Please check the Code in below

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request 


def url_to_jpg(i, url , File_Path):
    filename = 'image_{}.jpg'.format(i)
    full_path = '{}{}'.format(File_Path, filename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
    print('{} saved.'.format(filename))
    return None


FileName = "C:/Users/IT City/Desktop/Kwiat-USA/KavantaCSV.csv"
File_Path = "C:/Users/IT City/Desktop/Kwiat-USA/images"

urls = pd.read_csv(FileName)

for i , url in enumerate(urls.values):
    url_to_jpg(i, url , File_Path)
```

Need your Immediate help. Help will be highly Appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to decode it?
-or you can simply use the requests library.

```
r = requests.get(url) 
f = open(filename, "wb+")
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The url being passed to urlretrieve is an array. the urls.values gives a 2d-array.

it always helps if the stack trace is also posted.

Comment: Hi Adithay , The csv file contains only One column named "URL" single column

Comment: the return type will always be a 2d array. irrespective of the data. why don't you print the url variable in the url_to_jpg method and check it once.